# Параллельное выполнение двух программ на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой трудностью: у меня есть две программы 1.py, 2.py и отдельный файл с функциями func.py. Мне необходимо что бы 1.py и 2.py работали параллельно, сейчас я это реализую последовательным запуском программ.
Как можно автоматизировать процесс запуска программ?

Comment: Через мультипроцессинг

Comment: а какова архитектура файлов ("кто кого импортирует") ? каковы входные данные и откуда они берутся ? возможно, получится написать `batch`-файл для автоматизации запуска.

Comment: Если просто надо запустить два файла можно простым bat файлом обойтись.. Если через скрипт то мультипроцессинг или потоки

Comment: Попробую использовать мультипроцессинг, так как может понадобиться останавливать одну из программ при определенных условиях